# ERROR: SymGetLineFromAddr64, GetLastError: 487 (Address: )

Tags: c++, exception, callstack

I am trying to use the StackWalker which is used to get the call stacks. While when running, the 487 error shows. Does anybody have some idea?

Answer (score 5):

It just means that StackWalker couldn't find debugging information for the function at that point in the backtrace. You can just ignore it if you don't need know the source file and line number for that function. You can make it go way for functions in Windows components by using the Microsoft symbol server: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=311503

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've debugged into the program, and I found that the function SysGetLineFromAddr64 is failed. Do you know in what case which may cause this problem? The parameters I used is the current process and the address which is queried from the STACKFRAME64.

Comment: In order to find out what line number in which source file the address corresponds to `SysGetLineFromAddr64` needs to use a special database that's not an essential part of executables and DLLs called debugging information. In order to use the the debugging information, it's needs to be available somewhere where `SysGetLineFromAddr64` can find it. It can be in the EXE/DLL image itself, or it can be in a separate file that the EXE/DLL refers to. If it's in a separate file it needs to be in a location where it knows to look for it, like in the current directory or a symbol server.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Is there a specific solution?